# Cloning EF entity using ExtensionMethods from EF 4 to EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity

I'm trying to clone an EF entity using this extension method

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension method to Enitity Object .Cloning 
    /// Cloning the Object .If required this need to be followed by CleatEntity Objects
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Entity Object to be cloned </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// 
    public static T Clone<T>(this T source) where T : EntityObject
    {
        var obj = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            obj.WriteObject(stream, source);
            stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)obj.ReadObject(stream);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
var MyEntity = context.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault();
var newEntity = MyEntity.Clone(); // Here is my problem
```

But MyEntity never shows my extension method, it would be because I need to cast MyEntiy to EntityObject but it doesn't cast directly.

This code is part of a cloner object that works on ef 4. Now my question is how can I do to convert this code to work with EF 6.1?

NOTE: Full code here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137853/Cloning-the-Entity-object-and-all-related-children